# How to upgrade QGIS in CENTOS7.9?

Tags: centos7, qgis

I have tried to upgrade but the latest version available on yum repository is 2.14.9 .I have tried to download from qgis but there are constraint like upgradation of OS.

As the beginnner kindly provide any correct procedure to upgrade.